# silverlight only working under administrator account

Tags: silverlight

I have an application where the following steps happen:

1) User logs into their PC with a domain account.
2) User logs into application with an application account.
2) User selects some criteria to make application return data
3) The application returns data in a Silverlight screen that refreshes every 10 seconds.

If I login to SOME machines on a domain account, the application returns data fine, whereas on others it returns no data.  On these same machines, the application returns data IF I login with the local PC administrator account.  I've debugged the application, and I'm at a loss as to why this would happen other than there might be a bug in Silverlight that I can't find.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: It actually isn't happening on the computer that I debug on, so there isn't an isolated  bit of code that I can give you.  I'm assuming it has something to do with permissions or IIS.  I've enable the anonymous login option under IIS though.

Comment: Set it to "Run As Administrator" / "trusted application" so it has some freedom to run outside of [the sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470128(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about leaving this one hanging, but basically what I had to do here was create a new user on the machine, add them to the admin group and run the app from there.  It had to do with the Windows Thin Client OS I was using - I think.  Kind of a weird pain in the butt.